# PyLint is showing import-error for package installed in venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code on a Mac, I am getting a linting error that it can't find a package. I copied the package to `lib/python-edl-master` and I added it to the path in workspace settings like this:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "lib/python-edl-master" }
```

So the code runs fine, but I would like to avoid this linting error.  I also installed some other packages using pip in the venv at `env/lib/python-3.8/site-packages` and those are not showing any error.  The reason I chose to install this one separately is that I will be modifying it, so I want the code to be tracked in git.  Do I have to add the path separately to pylint somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The change above only applies to the terminal itself, not to the tools run by the extension itself. For that you will want to create a `.env` file and add your `PYTHONPATH` setting:

```
PYTHONPATH = lib/python-edl-master
```

By the way, the common practice for vendoring projects into your source code is via a subpackage in your project called `_vendor`. That way it sits within your code and becomes less of a special case.